# React Router : Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm looking for an answer to an error I get every time I try to make the React Router work.

This is a GitHub link with the error : https://github.com/delmotte/error-react-router

Just run `npm install` and `grunt` to see the error.

This is in `src/js/index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router';
import TodoListContainer from './components/TodoListContainer.jsx';
import About from './components/About.jsx';
import App from './components/App.jsx';

React.render((
    <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <Route path="about" component={About} />
            <Route path="todolist" component={TodoListContainer} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('main'));
```

Help me please?
Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant code. Links to code on other sites tend to decay, making any answers less useful to future visitors. Also include the stack trace so we know *where* the error is occurring.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue here. Basic example and I'm just following the first getting started guide. Only difference is that I'm importing my classes like you are where as the examples show the usage of React.createClass.